# Delegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, alamofire

I have a custom delegate/protocol setup. I use alamofire to make a get request, and then I parse the json. The json is arranged into Swift objects, and passed back to the collection view controller. Except the delegate to send them back never gets called. Everything else works perfectly though. Here is my relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, MainCatGallery {

var cats = [Cats]()
let theManager = ImgurAPIManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadCats()
    theManager.delegate = self

}

  func gotCatsArray(x: [Cats]) {
      self.cats = x
      self.collectionView?.reloadData()
  }
}
```

and:

```
  protocol MainCatGallery {
func gotCatsArray(x: [Cats])
}


class ImgurAPIManager: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = ImgurAPIManager()
let jsonClass = ParseJson()
var delegate:MainCatGallery?
var catGallery = [Cats]()

func getGallery() {
    Alamofire.request(Router.Get)
    .response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            self.catGallery = self.jsonClass.parseCatGalleryJson(jsonDict)
            for x in self.catGallery {
                print(x.url!)
            }
            self.delegate?.gotCatsArray(self.catGallery)

        }
        catch {

         }
      }

   }

}
```

All of this works fine--the print statement in the getGallery() function prints out each URL as expected. Just when it goes to call the delegate, it never passes the objects back to the view controller. And setting breakpoints shows that it never passes the data back.

I have used this exact same pattern before in other projects for delegates/protocols, and never had a problem. Any ideas why it isn't getting called?

Comment: Where and when do you call `getGallery`? Is it called by the view controller when it calls `loadCats()`?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of ImgurAPIManager and assigning the delegate to it. Either use your sharedInstance to set the delegate or make your delegate static.

Comment: @Roman yes loadCats() calls the get gallery method, but DanBeaulieu has answered correctly. ImgurAPIManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self is correct. put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: As a general rule, most delegates are stored as `weak` in a class to prevent retain cycles. This is partly because a subclass of (for example) `ImgurAPIManager` may implement the `MainCatGallery` protocol and use itself as its delegate (I've done this myself for an OS X view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ImgurAPIManager class you have a shared instance which is what you can use to set your delegate.

```
static let sharedInstance = ImgurAPIManager()
```

However, in your ViewController you've created a new instance and set your delegate:

```
let theManager = ImgurAPIManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    theManager.delegate = self
}
```

Change this line:

```
theManager.delegate = self
```

To this:

```
ImgurAPIManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self
```

---

As [Roman Sausarnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051126/roman-sausarnes) pointed out below:

And to avoid this kind of mixup in the future, you can mark your `ImgurAPIManager` initializer `private: private init() { }`. That way you can't accidentally create instances of it from outside the file. –

Comment: And to avoid this kind of mixup in the future, you can mark your `ImgurAPIManager` initializer `private`: `private init() { }`. That way you can't accidentally create instances of it from outside the file.